# Does one use spacing before and after a / slash in a sentence?

Tags: slash, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I write “comma/period” or “comma / period”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/should-i-write-comma-period-or-comma-period)

I'm trying to figure out what the correct spacing is for using a slash in a sentence.

For example the question: "How do you deal with characters leveling up too quickly for the module, due to side-quests/random encounters?"

Does one put a space before and after the slash>?

"word / word"

Or do you not put any spaces?

"word/word"

Or is the answer something else?